# Report Templates (.qpt) load as Map Templates in QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, reports

I have a report template (.qpt) file that I would like to load into a new project. I can load the template file from Layout Manager > New from Template. The problem is that it loads the template as though it is a map (print composer style) template, with none of the necessary panels and toolbars needed to work with and export a report.

In the Layout Manager the imported "report" template is shown with the map template symbol:

[image: map template symbol]

rather than the report template symbol:

[image: report symbol]